# create build number in git-svn environment

Tags: git, svn, maven, buildnumber-maven-plugin

Development and test builds are build from a *`git svn clone`* repository while release build are build from a pure `svn` checkout.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-buildnumber</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <useLastCommittedRevision>true</useLastCommittedRevision>
                <buildNumberPropertyName>build.buildNumber</buildNumberPropertyName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The `scm > developerConnection` is a `scm:svn` url and it seems that `buildnumber-maven-plugin` defaults to the scm provider defined in that url.

Is there a way to use a git scm provider if the project is cloned via git?

---

It seems that the scm provider can be swapped using

```
<providerImplementations>
    <svn>git</svn>
</providerImplementations>
```

At least Maven calls `git rev-parse --verify HEAD`  but it doesn't store the buildNumber.

Comment: If the project contains the scm:svn provider than i would assume no. If you change the scm entries than yes.